# iOS project fails to compile under xcodebuild for deployment target 7.0, but is fine for 6.0. Compiles for both under Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild

I have an iOS project that has iOS 6.0 as a deployment target. It builds fine both under Xcode and xcodebuilder (necessary for CI). However the client now wants the project to only be available for users who have iOS7+ installed.

No problem, I'll just increase the deployment target number right? Wrong!

Under Xcode the project continues to compile just fine. Under xcodebuild however, the project fails to compile with lots of errors like this:

> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
>   "std::string::_Rep::_S_empty_rep_storage", referenced from:
>          in drmNativeInterface

It's using `Adobe Primetime` and `drmNativeInterface` is part of that.

To help isolate the problem I've created a brand new, single-screen project and performed the following changes:

- Added the `drmNativeInterface` framework and the two Apple-supplied dependencies that are required for the project to build in Xcode, `MediaPlayer` and `AVFoundation` to `"Link Binary with Libraries"`. The Primetime documentation lists other dependencies as well but it makes no difference if I add those - these are the only 2 that are needed for a successful build under Xcode.
- Replaced the valid archs `"arm64 armv7 armv7s"` with `"armv6 armv7 armv7s"` (even though drmNativeInterface apparently contains i386, x86_64, armv7s and arm64 slices, even Xcode won't compile the project unless I switch arm64 for armv6).
- Set `"Build Active Architecture Only"` to NO for both configurations.
- And finally, added `"-lstdc++ -ObjC -all_load"` to `"Other Linker Flags"`.

Other than those few steps above, the project is stock single-screen: no code has been added.

Xcode will compile it but xcodebuild will not. For xcodebuild to compile it I have to switch the deployment target to 6.0 which defeats the client's request.

The CI xcodebuild command contains a few params but here's the minimised command I'm using for this test project:

> xcodebuild -project `"MyProject.xcodeproj"` -scheme `"MyProject"`

I've tried adding `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS`, `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` and `ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS` params in case xcodebuild was simply unable to use the paths contained within the project file but that made no difference.

If I remove the `drmNativeInterface` framework from the project - leaving the 2 Apple-based dependencies alone - the project compiles just fine for both Xcode and xcodebuild. But obviously this isn't a solution because I need that framework!

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this or how to fix it?

**NB: **

> There are a lot of questions on SO where projects will build in Xcode and not in xcodebuilder, but I couldn't find any where a project will build in xcodebuilder just fine for one deployment target and not for another.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've had problems before with multiple versions of Xcode installed on my machine. Did you set the correct version to be used by command line invocations using `xcode-select`?

Comment: I have a fresh installation of Yosemite on my machine and Xcode 6.3.2 is the only version that has been installed. The problem is reproduced on the CI server as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linking the libstdc++ library (in this case, libstdc++6.dylib to be exact) fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You lose the  `libstdc++6.dylib` in `Link Binary With Libraries`
Just add it like :
[image]

Comment: I'd already answered my own question before you posted this, but thanks for adding the gif for anyone new to Xcode who might not know how to do that.  :)